# Do poisson regression and exact poisson regression only differ in confidence interval?

Tags: poisson-regression, small-sample, fishers-exact-test, exact-test

The point estimates from the two approaches are the same, right?
I plan to use exact Poisson regression for a study, since the events could be sparse after adjusting for a few covariates.
Is there anything to be aware about exact Poisson regression? I have never implemented it before.

Comment: Point estimates and confidence intervals differ in exact poisson regression models.  These models are also known as permutation or conditional models since they are formed by conditioning on the sufficient statistics of all nuisance parameters.  In effect these methods consider the set of all data arrays that have the fixed values for the sufficient statistics we condition on.  According to Cox (1970), p-values occur exactly rather than as crude approximations.  These models should be used when one has a small sample size relative to the total number of parameters (including nuisance). Use SAS

Comment: Thank you. I tried in SAS. The point estimates are indeed slightly different. I wonder why SAS does not output rate ratio..

Comment: Just found estimate=both under the exact statement will give estimate for rate ratio.

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation about this method. It makes sense. Permutation + Condition on the all the permutations that give the same sufficient statistic for nuisance factors.